# Reverse geocoding in matlab

Tags: matlab, reverse-geocoding, mapquest

I have written a small piece of code to be able to reverse geocode based on lat, long information.

I mainly am stuck in 2 ways;

1. Here I have tried to use the google api as I am not sure how to code the mapquest api for reverse geocoding.... could some one advice how to code this in matlab
2. When I run the script an error pops up for urlread:

   ```
   ??? Error using ==> urlread at 111   
   Error downloading URL. Your network connection may be down  
   or your proxy settings improperly configured.  
   Error in ==> revgeoCode at 46  
   buffer = urlread(url)
   ```

   I have tried setting the proxi address and port but that fails. Any way the [mapquest api](http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/#reverse) will solve this or any other way to get around it?

I am not brilliant with coding so please be kind.....this is what I have.

```
function [c] = revgeoCode(lat, lon)

if isempty(lat) || ischar(lon)
    error('Invalid address provided, must be a string');
end

url = sprintf('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=%.4f,%.4f&sensor=true', lat, lon)       

buffer = urlread(url)

results = regexp(buffer, '<formatted_address>(.*?)<', 'tokens') ;
for k = 1 : length(results),  fprintf('%s\n', results{k}{1}) ;  end

end
```

Comment: Can you share the actual error?

Comment: Unfortunately `urlread` does not give useful error messages... Does `urlread('http://www.google.com')` work? If not, than the proxy probably is the issue

Comment: No that doesn't work either. I have tried fixing the proxi settings. Is there a way to get around it?

Comment: Nope - you'll have to fix them I guess. Check http://superuser.com/questions/346372/how-do-i-know-what-proxy-server-im-using (for windows)

Comment: OK I will work on that. Would you be able to advice on the other query about adding a mapquest api to the code?